# Cannot find the element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

https://www.xendpay.com

Here is the page. It is necessary to pull out an input from it

```
<input id = "paymentAmount" class = "input-text pull-left" tabindex = "1" name = "paymentAmount" type = "text">
```

And enter another text into it.

I tried to do this through ID, through xpath, through @name. What could be the problem?

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'paymentAmount')]")))
```

[image]

Comment: I enter the page and didn't even find element with this ID and name. using: 

***len(driver.find_elements_by_name('paymentAmount'))***
I've got 0 elements with this ID and name, tell some more

Comment: I don’t see either, but there is one on the page. This block is loaded using js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's iFrame, you should switch to it, wait for loader to disappear, delete old value in the input and than set yours.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.xendpay.com/")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "iFrameResizer0")))
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "loader")))
payment_amount = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "paymentAmount")))
ActionChains(driver).double_click(payment_amount).send_keys(Keys.DELETE).send_keys("999").perform()
```

Comment: It's a very beautiful

Answer (score 1):

Your element is located in iframe html tag.
You need to switch to the iframe (iFrameResizer0 in the link you provided):

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("iFrameResizer0")));

... do your find here.

// switch back to default
driver.DefaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

got it:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("iFrameResizer0")
driver.find_elements_by_name('paymentAmount')
```